# How to document property that were added to object.prototype with Object.defineProperties() using jsDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a constructor:

```
/**
 * Language class.
 * @param {string|String} abbreviation
 * @param {string|String} name
 * @param {number|Number} id
 * @throws {ReferenceError}
 * @constructor
 */
function Language(abbreviation, name, id) {

    //Parameters validation
    {
        if (abbreviation === null) {
            throw new ReferenceError();
        }

        if (TypeValidator.IsString(abbreviation)) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add property to Language class prototype using  Object.defineProperties():

```
Object.defineProperties(
    Language.prototype,
    {
        'ABBREVIATION': {
            configurable: false,
            writable    : false,
            enumerable  : false,
            get: function () {
                return get.call(_abbreviation, this);
            }
        },
    }
);
```

How to document with jsDoc new getter as part of Language.prototype, and how to describe the getter (do i have to use @function...)?

Comment: `@function` is definitely the wrong option; you're not defining a method on `Language`, even though one step of accessing the value of `ABBREVIATION` is to run a function. Your documentation should tell developers that they can do `someLang.ABBREVIATION` and not do `someLang.ABBREVIATION()`. I'm not a JSDoc expect at all, but I think you can use a [`@property {whatever} ABBREVIATION` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html#examples) above your `function  Language(...)` constructor, to indicate in your documentation that developers can expect `Language` to have an `ABBREVIATION` property.

Comment: @apsillers  
I added " /** *@property {string} Language*/ to 'Language' constructor, that doesn't work. As I see, information about property wan't documented by jsDoc. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Putting a `/* @member {whatever} ABBREVIATION */` line *inside* your constructor might also work (perhaps at the bottom of the function so it doesn't attach to any other line of code). (Sorry I can't be of more help!)